# Windows Foundation in C# console project

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I would like to use Windows.Device.Sensor in my console project, but I can't add reference to Windows and Windows.Foundation in this project.

How I can do that ?

Comment: Take a look at article http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToCallWinRTAPIsInWindows8FromCDesktopApplicationsWinRTDiagram.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Like AVD say in this comment, the solution can be found here : http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToCallWinRTAPIsInWindows8FromCDesktopApplicationsWinRTDiagram.aspx